# Typescript transform output into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this array of records which is being duplicated for each users's courses:

```
id  name  courseId  title   
1   user 1  11  course A
1   user 1  22  course B
2   user 2  33  course C
3   user 3  44  course D
```

But actually I want response like this, I want to remove the duplicated record of user and put courses as an array against each user

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user 1",
    "courses": [
      {
        "courseId": 11,
        "title": "course A",
      },
      {
        "courseId": 22,
        "title": "course B",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "user 2",
    "courses": [
      {
        "courseId": 33,
        "title": "course C",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "user 3",
    "courses": [
      {
        "courseId": 44,
        "title": "course D",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am very new to Typescript, how can I achieve this response in an optimized way?

Answer (score 1):

You can define 2 types for `User` and `Course`, and then group them together with a new type called `UserWithCourses`

For the array mapping logic, you can use `reduce`

```
type Course = {
    courseId?: number,
    title?: string
}

type User = {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

const input: (User & Course)[] = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "user 1",
    courseId: 11,
    title: "course A"
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "user 1",
    courseId: 22,
    title: "course B"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "user 2",
    courseId: 33,
    title: "course C"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "user 3",
    courseId: 44,
    title: "course D"
}, { id: 4, name: "user 4" }]

type UserWithCourses = User & { courses?: Course[] | null }

const output: UserWithCourses[] = input.reduce((result: UserWithCourses[], item: User & Course): UserWithCourses[] => {
    const user: UserWithCourses | undefined = result.find(({ id }) => item.id === id)

    const course: Course = {
                courseId: item.courseId,
                title: item.title
            }

    if(user && user.courses) {
        user.courses.push(course)
    } else {
        result.push({
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name,
            courses: item.courseId ? [course] : null
        })
    }
    return result
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-FcC58FFAIMJVpO+DHhMA5-lF9uW30G4Zmy2-gwG38LzWZ9fgBax9TqFAaAkrnFjLzhF2iAoK58EonyqsAyCMFAu7AJ0CQxCu+BCnAohKsIcCyH4IpihEQA)

Comment: There is also a case with there will be no course assigned to a user, but the user will appear in list. e.g add this record to the input array aswell: {
    id: 4,
    name: "user 4"
}

Comment: You can make `courseId` and `title` in `Course` optional with `?`. By the way, I also updated my answer for the sake of your requirement @StormTrooper

Comment: Cant we avoid the code repetition?

Comment: Also is this possible to create a single interface for this, i stead of type Course = {
    courseId?: number,
    title?: string
}

type User = {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

Comment: If we try to combine `Course` and `User`, it will cause type duplication in `UserWithCourses`.

Comment: I also reduced some logic to make it less duplicated in my updated answer

Comment: I was wondering what If a user also have multiple hobbies and multiple cars,

Comment: Wouldn't this become crowded?